# Retrieving Google Plus share count with wp_remote_post

Tags: google-plus, social-sharing, curl, wp-remote-post

So I've spent most of my morning working on my website's customized social share buttons. Reading out Twitter and Facebook shares were no problem, but Google Plus is a real challenge, as they don't offer an easy-to-use GET API.

I found a working technique using barebones CURL ( http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/comment-page-1/ ). But previously, I've tried hard to get it to work with Wordpress' functions like wp_remote_post and failed. Anyone can tell me what I've been doing wrong?

Here is what I managed to get together. Two different requests fail:

```
$google_url = 'https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ';
$headers    = array('Content-type' => 'application/json');
$body       = array( "method"   => "pos.plusones.get"
                    ,"id"       => "p"
                    ,"params"   => array(   "nolog"     => true
                                            ,"id"       => $url
                                            ,"source"   => "widget"
                                            ,"userId"   => "@viewer"
                                            ,"groupId"  => "@self"
                                        )
                    ,"jsonrpc"  =>"2.0"
                    ,"key"      => "p"
                    ,"apiVersion" => "v1"
                );

$response = wp_remote_post( $google_url , array( 'method'   => 'POST'
                                                ,'headers'  => $headers
                                                ,'body'     => $body    ) );

if (!is_wp_error($response)) {
    $resp = json_decode($response['body'],true);
    _e($response['body']);
}
else
{
    _e('error');
}
// Another attempt to get data with WP_Http 
$request = new WP_Http;
$result = $request->request( $google_url , array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $body, 'headers' => $headers ) );

if (!is_wp_error($result)) {
    $resp = json_decode($result['body'],true);
    _e($result['body']);
}
else
{
    _e('error AGAIN');
}
```

PS: The API key is a public one for developers.

Answer (score 3):

I see that the question is 2 years old, but I worked hard two days to find solution of the very same problem and here is my code (for me works 100%).

```
$json_string = wp_remote_request('https://clients6.google.com/rpc',
array(
    'method'    => 'POST',
    'body'      => '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"'.rawurldecode(get_permalink()).'","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]',
    'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json')
));

$json = json_decode($json_string['body'], true);



if(isset($json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'])){
   echo intval($json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count']);
}else{
   echo'0';
}
```

The big difference from the code above is that I send request in JSON format, not as an array.